# Jquery widget open in a new iframe and doctype?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've this third party plugin where it will load a complete new doctype into my existing html file. I've specifically added custom css to overwrite the existing styling within the widget, but somehow my CSS doesn't work. I also noticed my javascript will not have affect within the widget itself as if the entire widget's html is being loaded from a different page. Can anyone give me a heads up as to how to edit the 3rd party loaded content?

code example:

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<div class="widget">
<!--widget start here--->
<iframe src="http://snapwidget.com/sl/?u=ZWxsZW1hbGF5c2lhfGlufDI5MHwzfDN8fHllc3w1fGZhZGVPdXR8b25TdGFydHx5ZXM=&amp;v=9114" >
<IDOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <!--html here-->
    </body>
</html>
</iframe>
<!--widget end here--->
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You cannot access the contents of an iframe if they are hosted on a different domain. It's called the Same Origin Policy

Comment: Yes, you can't access the Iframe contents if it in different domain.